# gspread to google sheet TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]

Tags: python, gspread

The connection attempt failed because the connecting party did not respond correctly after a period of time or the connected host did not respond.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('C:/Users/robin/Desktop/work/secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("python to sheets").sheet1
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/robin/Desktop/work/google.py", line 9, in <module>
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\gspread\__init__.py", line 38, in authorize
    client.login()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 51, in login
    self.auth.refresh(http)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 545, in refresh
    self._refresh(http)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 749, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 780, in _do_refresh_request
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\transport.py", line 282, in request
    connection_type=connection_type)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1976, in request
    cachekey,
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1640, in _request
    conn, request_uri, method, body, headers
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1546, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1384, in connect
    raise socket_err
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1317, in connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]
```